# How to convert Map to Bytes and save to internal storage

Tags: java, android, file-io

How can I convert my `Map<Integer, String`> to `byte[]`, and then write it to internal storage? I currently have:

```
        try {
            FileOutputStream fos = context.openFileOutput(Const.FILE_CATEGORIES, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            fos.write(null);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            // reload and create the file again
        }
```

But..I don't know how to get the `Map` into the correct format, and then decode it back to it's original format once I need to load it again. I need to recreate this file once per week, and load it on application startup.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

1. Using serialization in java you can easily parse any serializable
   objects to byte stream. Try to use the ObjectInputStream and the
   ObjectOuputStream.
2. Use json to restore. You can use google-gson to convert Java
   objects to JSON and vice-versa.
3. Use Parcel in android. The class android.os.Parcel is designd to pass data
   between the components in android(activity, service), but you can still use it to do data persistence.
   Just remember do not send the data to internet since differenct
   platforms may have different algorithm to do parsing.

I wrote a demo for serialization , have a try.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    // Create raw data.
    Map<Integer, String> data = new HashMap<Integer, String>();
    data.put(1, "hello");
    data.put(2, "world");
    System.out.println(data.toString());

    // Convert Map to byte array
    ByteArrayOutputStream byteOut = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    ObjectOutputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream(byteOut);
    out.writeObject(data);

    // Parse byte array to Map
    ByteArrayInputStream byteIn = new ByteArrayInputStream(byteOut.toByteArray());
    ObjectInputStream in = new ObjectInputStream(byteIn);
    Map<Integer, String> data2 = (Map<Integer, String>) in.readObject();
    System.out.println(data2.toString());
}
```

Comment: This approach has the drawback that if the map class gets changed, all the persisted values are invalid.

Comment: and how to save these in file?

Answer (score 2):

I know I am subscribing to an old thread but it popped out in my google search.
So I will leave my 5 cents here:

You can use **org.apache.commons.lang3.SerializationUtils** which has these two methods:

```
/**
 * Serialize the given object to a byte array.
 * @param object the object to serialize
 * @return an array of bytes representing the object in a portable fashion
 */
public static byte[] serialize(Object object);

/**
 * Deserialize the byte array into an object.
 * @param bytes a serialized object
 * @return the result of deserializing the bytes
 */
public static Object deserialize(byte[] bytes);
```

Answer (score 0):

Either serialize like faylon mentioned, or implement your own mechanism to save and load your map. By saving, you iterate over all elements and save key-value pairs. By loading, you add them back. Implementing your own mechanism has the advantage that you can still use your persisted values when your program is used with another Java version.